# ¿Porque me da un error de sintaxis en el constructor al colocar "public string $variable"?

Tags: php, php8

Tengo un problema con un constructor que estoy intentando crear en php, no entiendo porque me marca error de sintaxis cuando escribo el constructor de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo se se debe a la version de php o que estoy haciendo mal, ahora bien si le quito al constructor todos los **public** en pantalla me imprime el siguiente error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Producto::__construct()
> must be an instance of string, string given

Tampoco entiendo ese error, mi clase y mi función la estoy mandado a llamar de esta forma:

```
$producto = new Producto('Teclado', 200, true);
$producto->mostrarProducto();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($producto);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los `public` en los parámetros te sobran, eso está claro.

Y los tipos (`string`, `int`, `bool`) también te sobran si la versión de PHP que corre el script es **anterior a PHP 7**.

```
public function __construct($nombre, $precio, $disponible) {
    //
}
```

Antes de PHP 7, la sugerencia de tipo solo se puede usar para forzar los tipos de objetos y arrays. En el caso de tu constructor, se espera un objeto de la clase string, pero se le está pasando una cadena (escalar).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/how-to-resolve-must-be-an-instance-of-string-string-given-prior-to-php-7

Comment: Muchas gracias, me estaba confundiendo entonces con mi versión de php